# Drupal - PHP - HTML - CSS - Render Tabs

Tags: php, html, css, drupal, drupal-7

I'm have a problem and I don't really know how to fix it. I'm trying to style the Tabs above my forum made with Drupal(see picture)

[image: tabs]

For some reason it always renders the tabs like on the picture. This is because I'm using the `render` function (`print render($tabs)`). I don't know how to get the names of the tabs. They are in a Array called `$tabs`, but this array returns this(See picture)

[image: Output]

Here is everything summarized:

I want to design Drupal's default tabs, but there is one problem, I can't get the names of the tabs without using `print render($tabs)`. But this function already styles the tabs.

Current code:

```
<?php if ($tabs): ?>
      <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified">
        <li class="active"><?php print_r render($tabs);?></li>
      </ul>
<?php endif ?>
```

- EDIT

When you click the tab, it has to redict to a URL. with the `render` function, it does this automatically. Is it also possible to do this?

Comment: I don't fully understand. If your tabs are already there and you only want to change its design, you should only use CSS. If you are creating a template , you need to call them there first, and then create CSS styles as well to style them. Do you mean change how they look, when you say "style the tabs"?